# C++ convert ULONG_PTR to array of hexadecimal values

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to convert ULONG_PTR variable to array of hexadecimal values, for example the following variable-

```
ULONG_PTR a = 1406993872
```

I want to convert it to the following arrray-

```
unsigned char hexArray[] = {0x53, 0xDD, 0x05, 0xD0}
```

What is the simplest way to do it using C++?

Comment: All [objects in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) can be viewed as an array of bytes (note that the reverse is not true), so you can get what you want with a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @user4581301 I guess you meant something like this- unsigned char hexArray[] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(a) but I get an error- "initialization with “{…}” expected for aggregate object "

Comment: Apologies. For that use case you cannot cast. The point I was trying to make is `hexArray` is likely redundant. Most places where you would use `hexArray` you could instead use `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is with a union:

```
union myunion {
    ULONG_PTR *a;
    unsigned char hexArray[sizeof(ULONG_PTR)];
};
```

`a` and `hexArray` will share the same memory space, but be treated with their respective types.